# Extended User Model - Conditional URL Redirect

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have extended the user model for my Django project to allow for a little more flexibility from the native admin app. I have a number of different user groups that on login, I would like to redirect to a unique template. Users will only be assigned to one group. When attempting to do this is the views.py file, I receive an AttributeError stating that "type object User has no attribute 'groups'. Even when using User.group.filter, an attribute error for 'filter' occurs. In the template, I am able to retrieve the user's group information via "{{user.groups.all.0}}" correctly.

Please see the code below for the User Model and the views.py.

Extended User Model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
    validators=[validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'),
    _('invalid'))])
   first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=50)
   email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255, unique=True,
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
   is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False,
   date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
   #added all required fields except email
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
   objects = UserManager()
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


from User_Profile.models import User

@login_required
def home(request):
    if User.groups.filter(name__in["Group1"]):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('laucnh'))
```

Comment: Indeed, the User *model class* itself doesn't have any groups. Only an instance of User - such as the current user - has groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current user from the [`request.user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user):

```
request.user.groups.filter(name__in["Group1"])
```

You may also utilize [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

> Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not.
>   This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way
>   possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal
>   QuerySet query.

```
if request.user.groups.filter(name__in["Group1"]).exists():
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. After entering the request.user, worked flawlessly. Thanks.